# Как присвоить полю объекта количество связанных сущностей?

Tags: java, sql, база-данных, spring-jpa, hsqldb

Делаю приложение на Spring-MVC, использую в качестве бд HSQLDB. Имеется сущность Film:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "films")
public class Film extends AbstractBaseEntity {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.FETCH)
    private List<Vote> votes;
```

Эта сущность отношением @OneToMany связана с сущностью Vote:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "votes")
public class Vote extends AbstractBaseEntity {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "film_id")
    private Film film;
```

На самом деле мне не нужно вытаскивать список голосов вместе с фильмом. Я делаю это только для того, чтобы узнать количество голосов на основании длины списка голосов. Я хочу изменить сущность Film таким образом:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "films")
public class Film extends AbstractBaseEntity {
    
    private Integer votes;
```

Т.е. не вытаскивать все голоса из репозитория, а получать только их количество. Каким SQL запросом мне следует воспользоваться в данном случае? Мне нужно, чтобы при вытаскивании из репозитория сущности Film, её полю votes присваивалось бы количество связанных с данным фильмом голосов.

Comment: select count(*)

Comment: @DeMmAge я знаю команду count. Меня интересует, как сделать требуемое в рамках одного запроса, без отдельного вытаскивания количества голосов. Как сделать так, чтобы количество голосов автоматически маппилось на поле votes в Film